# Not sure how to do parse tree when a ()'s is involved?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I have the following grammar :

```
  E -> E+T | E-T | T
  T -> T*F | T/F | F
  F -> i | (E)
```

And this string :

```
(i+i)*i
```

What's messing me up is how I would incorporate the ()'s?

Attempt:

E -> T

Left sub-branch of T = T -> F -> i

Mid-branch = *

Right sub-branch of T = F -> (E) -> E + T ..... (E -> i, T -> i)

I'm not sure if that is understandable but I'm not sure how else to write parse tree here. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your attempt appears to relate to `i*(i+i)` rather than `(i+i)*i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to present the parse tree is as a tree diagram (usually with the root at the top), where each node in the tree is a symbol, and the tree's 'child' relation reflects the steps in the derivation.

E.g., for `i*(i+i)`, the parse tree might look something like this:

```
    E
    |
    T
    |
+---+---+
|   |   |
T   *   F
|       |
F   +---+---+
|   |   |   |
i   (   E   )
        |
    +---+---+
    |   |   |
    E   +   T
    |       |
    T       F
    |       |
    F       i
    |
    i
```

or like this:

```
        E
        |
        T
        |
+---+-----------+
|   |           |
T   |           F
|   |           |
F   |   +-------+-------+
|   |   |       |       |
|   |   |       E       |
|   |   |       |       |
|   |   |   +---+---+   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   E   |   T   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   T   |   F   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   F   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
i   *   (   i   +   i   )
```

As you can see, parentheses don't pose a special problem.